# std::stack<int> with max function?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How does one implement a `stack<int>` with a max operation which the max function has a complexity of O(1) and it uses O(n) extra memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea would be to keep track of the max through using pairs in the stack. If you insert something into the stack, you update the max accordingly.

```
class Stack {
private: 
    stack<pair<int,int>> s;

public:
    bool empty() const {
        return s.empty();
    }

    int max() const {
        assert (empty() == false);
        return s.top().second;
    }

    int pop() {
        int ans = s.top().first;
        s.pop();
        return ans;
    }

    void push(int x) {
        if (s.empty() || x > s.top().second)
        {
            s.emplace(x, x);
        }
        else
        {
            s.emplace(x, s.top().second);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: whoops. Thanks for the catch Glenn and thanks for the fix @leemes

Comment: this solution is nice because it treats the current stack as an invarient so you can safely save the max

Answer (score 2):

Maintain a sorted `list` of `int`

Each stack node points to the `list` entry

`max` just returns the head (`min` would be the tail) of the `list`

When you `push` also do a sorted insert into the `list` *(note that this will now be O(n) but that wasn't precluded)*

When you `pop` do a delete of the associated entry in the `list`

Getting the head is O(1). The `list` will be of size O(n).

Answer (score 2):

You can keep 2 stacks in your structure, one acts as a normal stack. The other one is used for max value storage(let's call it `max_stack`).

You only want to push a value in the `max_stack` if the value pushed is greater or equal to the value at the top of `max_stack`. You only want to pop `max_stack` if the value popped from the normal stack is equal to the top of `max_stack`. So top `max_stack` always holds the max value in current stack.

For example:
push in 2,1,2,1,3,2,3, the `max_stack` will look like 2,2,3,3.

Comment: what about dups: 3,1,3,1 ?

Comment: like I said, you push when it's greater or EQUAL than the top. In case of 3,1,3,1 the stack will be 1,3,3.